# How to position a fixed background image *always* on bottom of mobile browsers? (CSS)

Tags: css, mobile, safari, microsoft-edge, opera

I'm using a fixed background image aligned to the bottom.

```
background: url(image.jpg) bottom center no-repeat fixed;
```

Now there's a problem with some mobile browsers e.g. Opera, Edge Chromium and Safari. There are browser bars at the top or bottom of the apps which were hiding when scrolling down the page. You follow?

When this bar disappears the background image stays in position and doesn't move down to the new screen margin.

How can you fix this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: You can reset the border, padding and margin in css to make sure only your css property works.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your meaning... I've updated the question a little bit, maybe the problem ist now more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the footer CSS style, make sure the bottom property is set to "0".

The following sample works well on my side (Edge Chromium on IOS), please refer to it.

```
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            height: 1200px;
        }
        .footer {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            height:50px;
            background: url("images/photographer.jpg") bottom center no-repeat fixed;
      }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The background-image Property</h1>

<p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br>
<p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br>\
<p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br>
   <p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br>
   <p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br>
   <p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br>
   <p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br>
   <p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br>
   <p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br><p>Hello World!</p><br>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look!